# Usage of colon and equals signs in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class PrepareTableOperator(BaseOperator):
   def _load_table(self):
      drop_table_query: str = ( "drop table if exists " + self.get_table() )
```

I'm a complete newbie to python but I do have a bit of a Java background.
What I don't get is the usage of colons in python. I've googled around, and it's used for slicing and for starting function definitions. But there's no 'def' syntax in the above, so to me this doesn't look like a function.

My question is, what is the colon in Python, is it another assignment operator for dictionary values, similar to a key value pair? Is that what it's doing here? What is it doing here, essentially?

Comment: yes, it can be used within a dictionary to define a key value pair

Comment: If this is the case, please provide the *entire* minimally reproducible code, as in the start and end of the dictionary definition (i.e.`{`, `}`)

Comment: [what is a colon for in python](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+colon+for+in+python+stackoverflow+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk01Xsr0I-8pOP9srnBTeU_dldXlQbA:1597953570741&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis8s33yKrrAhU0GTQIHYhoBh8QrQIoBHoECAYQBQ&biw=1920&bih=975)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code snippet, it is a type annotation. It is a relatively new feature of Python that lets you keep track of the data types, so in this case, it is declaring that `drop_table_query` is a string.

Type annotations are checked by IDE, but not enforced by the Python interpreter. This means that `drop_table_query` could actually be an `int` and Python itself won't complain. The type annotation is just a sort of recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

What it is doing here is defining that the variable will be a string (`str` data type).  The colon is used in while loops, for loops, if statements, and functions. The colon helps the code flow into the following indented block. A single equal sign is used to assign a value to a variable, a double equal sign is used for conditions, like `if var == other_var:`. There is also `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, and `/=`. Those are used to shorten things like, `var = var + 1`, to `var += 1`.